# A github autograding problem i couldn't figure out

Tags: ruby, github

i was given a homework by my instructor which i was supposed to upload into autograding system and i did.
And even though the program flawlessly works in my ruby interpreter, it prints an error in autograding system:

This is my output of the program:
Range: 1453-2011
Sum: 129339
Binary: 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1

This is what resulted in autograding system:
❌ Example1
::error::The output for test Example1 did not match%0AExpected:%0ARange: 1453-2011%0ASum: 129339%0ABinary: 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1%0AActual:%0ARange: 1453-2011%0ASum: 129339%0ABinary: 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1

I didn't understand the reason why this error occurred at all. The output of my program is absolutely the same as the demanded output. Can you please explain?

It's basically a program that asks an input for which should be used to create an array with a range and the sum of the prime numbers within that range. It also asks for the binary representation of the sum of the prime numbers in that range:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

def set_number(index1, index2) # Create an array with a range by asking the minimum and maximum points of the range specified by the user.
   Array(index1..index2)
 
end

def prime?(number)  # Is the number prime?
  if number < 2 
        return false
  elsif (2..Integer.sqrt(number)).each do
        |divisor| if number % divisor == 0 
        return false
    end
     end
       return number
  end
end

def decimal_to_binary(number) # Convert the number from decimal to binary.
  number = number.to_i
  if number == 0 
     return 0
  end
 
  binary = []
  while number != 0
    binary = binary << String(number % 2) 
    number = number / 2
  end
  binary
end

index1, index2 = gets.chomp.split.map(&:to_i)
array = set_number(index1, index2)

puts "Range: #{index1}-#{index2}"

primes = []
array.each do |x|
  primes << x if prime?(x)
end

sum = 0
primes.each {|element| sum = sum + element}
puts "Sum: #{sum}"

binary = decimal_to_binary(sum)
puts "Binary: #{binary.reverse.join(" " " ")}"
```

I expected the autograding system to verify the result which is correct and pass to the another example but it didn't.

Comment: Show the _exact_ task definition, please. Usually when the task is supposed to be auto-evaluated by some automatic grading system, the requested output is very lean and clear, like a single number (string, list, ...) - something that is easy to test vs different inputs. Your program produces noisy output instead - you don't print just a sum, you print `Sum: <sum>`, you print binary with 2 spaces between digits etc etc, so depending on how the test system is built any single whitespace in non-expected place can turn the test red...

Comment: Hi! Really appreciated your answer, i changed join parameter to join(" ") and tested again it worked!! thanks for making me realise there were 2 whitespaces between the binaries haha